# swap an image to a small area of a larger image

Tags: javascript, image-manipulation, mouseover

I have an image showing 42 classmates from 1958. I want to map each small face and replace it with a current portrait on a mouse rollover. The swapimage code works ok, but the new portrait is the size of the original complete image.

```
<area shape="rect" coords="72,260,143,346" href="#" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Image1','','../LoisS.jpg',1)" alt="" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()">
```

How can I get the small image to stay small and overlay only the original face, leaving the original large image in place behind it?  Can I somehow amend the code above?  [I'm no good at writing my own js or css].

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at jQuery. This makes showing a bigger version of an image rather easy.

Please have a look at: http://jsfiddle.net/DVDhs/. I tried to make something similar which might be what you're after.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give these a try.